# How chrome extension monitor window minimize event and get activated tab info in that window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to write an extension which will run some func when the window is maximized/minimized, and the func needs tab info before minimized as well. I tried chrome.windows.onFocusChanged, however, it only works when there are multiple windows. Is there any way or JS scripts that can detect whether a window is minimized?

Comment: I'm running `onFocusChanged` with a single window open and I'm receiving the event, are you running it in a background script?

Comment: yep, I run it in background.  But if I put it in a content script, it gives an error: cannot read property onFocusChanged of undefined.

Comment: Correct, your content script doesn't have access to the `onFocusedChanged` api. You would use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, callback)` to pass command based messages to your background script that it will listen for and perform certain actions. You can read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging